# Error while starting Wildfly 11 App Server - persistence unit named null

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, wildfly

I'm developing a maven based JSF+JPA+EJB 3.2 Project using Eclipse and Wildfly 11.
While starting the App Server am getting the following error :

```
    20:37:27,664 INFO  [org.jboss.weld.deployer] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYWELD0003: Processing weld deployment erpmini.war

20:37:28,116 INFO  [org.hibernate.validator.internal.util.Version] (MSC service thread 1-4) HV000001: Hibernate Validator 5.3.5.Final

20:37:28,552 INFO  [org.jboss.as.ejb3.deployment] (MSC service thread 1-4) WFLYEJB0473: JNDI bindings for session bean named 'UserManagementServiceSlsb' in deployment unit 'deployment "erpmini.war"' are as follows:


java:global/erpmini/UserManagementServiceSlsb!com.itsys.erp.server.commonservices.usermgmt.UserManagementService

java:app/erpmini/UserManagementServiceSlsb!com.itsys.erp.server.commonservices.usermgmt.UserManagementService

java:module/UserManagementServiceSlsb!com.itsys.erp.server.commonservices.usermgmt.UserManagementService

java:jboss/exported/erpmini/UserManagementServiceSlsb!com.itsys.erp.server.commonservices.usermgmt.UserManagementService

java:global/erpmini/UserManagementServiceSlsb

java:app/erpmini/UserManagementServiceSlsb

java:module/UserManagementServiceSlsb

20:37:29,879 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-4) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."erpmini.war".INSTALL: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."erpmini.war".INSTALL: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment "erpmini.war"

at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:172)

at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)

at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)

at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)

at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0041: Component class com.itsys.erp.server.commonservices.usermgmt.slsbadapter.UserManagementServiceSlsb for component UserManagementServiceSlsb has errors:

WFLYJPA0033: Can't find a persistence unit named null in deployment "erpmini.war"

at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor$1.handle(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:157)

at org.jboss.as.ee.component.ClassDescriptionTraversal.run(ClassDescriptionTraversal.java:54)

at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.processClassConfigurations(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:186)

at org.jboss.as.ee.component.deployers.ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.deploy(ModuleJndiBindingProcessor.java:143)

at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:165)

... 5 more

20:37:30,098 INFO  [org.infinispan.factories.GlobalComponentRegistry] (MSC service thread 1-2) ISPN000128: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.8.Final

20:37:31,825 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 63) WFLYCLINF0002: Started client-mappings cache from ejb container

20:37:32,131 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) WFLYCTL0013: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "erpmini.war")]) - failure description: {

    "WFLYCTL0080: Failed services" => {"jboss.deployment.unit.\"erpmini.war\".INSTALL" => "WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase INSTALL of deployment \"erpmini.war\"

    Caused by: org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitProcessingException: WFLYEE0041: Component class com.itsys.erp.server.commonservices.usermgmt.slsbadapter.UserManagementServiceSlsb for component UserManagementServiceSlsb has errors:

WFLYJPA0033: Can't find a persistence unit named null in deployment \"erpmini.war\""},

    "WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:" => ["jboss.deployment.unit.\"erpmini.war\".beanmanager"],

    "WFLYCTL0180: Services with missing/unavailable dependencies" => [

    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"erpmini.war\".weld.weldClassIntrospector is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"erpmini.war\".beanmanager]",

    "jboss.deployment.unit.\"erpmini.war\".batch.artifact.factory is missing [jboss.deployment.unit.\"erpmini.war\".beanmanager]"

    ]

}
```

I'm injecting the EntityManager in stateless bean:

```
@Stateless
public class UserManagementServiceSlsb implements UserManagementService {

     /** The Entity Manager */
     @PersistenceContext(name = "TELCOAppPU")
     private EntityManager entityManager;

     private UserManagementService userMgmtService;
 ....
}
```

Why the Container is not able to find persistence.xml file? persistence.xml is present in META-INF directory. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks. 
UPDATE :
here is Project dir structure , persistence.xml is present in META-INF directory.

[Project dir structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCjpR.png)

persistence.xml contains Entity classes and MySql database connection details.

```
<persistence-unit name="TELCOAppPU">
    <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>com.itsys.erp.server.dal.entities.City</class>
    <class>com.itsys.erp.server.dal.entities.Machine</class>
    <class>com.itsys.erp.server.dal.entities.Product</class>
    <class>com.itsys.erp.server.dal.entities.ProductType</class>
    <class>com.itsys.erp.server.dal.entities.ProductionLog</class>
    ...
    <properties>
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/erpdb" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="root" />
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: What does your `persistence.xml` contain and where is it located?

Comment: persistence.xml is present in META-INF directory. I have put project structure in the question. persistence.xml contains Entity classes and mysql database connection details. Updated the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved it by adding `resources` folder (as source folder) to the path `src/main/resources` and moving the `META-INF`  folder to `resources` folder, which in turn tells maven to put all files under `resources` directory to `target/classes` and in `WEB-INF/classes` in the WAR.

Answer (score 0):

Try placing your `persistance.xml` file inside `WEB-INF (src/main/webapp/WEB-INF)` directory, Since in case of a `war`, that is where you are supposed to place your `persisntence.xml` file.

Comment: yes just now I read that in JPA 2.2 specification under 8.2 section. My project is a maven Web App project and I don't see `WEB-INF` dir under `src/main/java/webapp`. So I created the `WEB-INF/classes` directory and moved the `persistence.xml` file over there. But this shows error icon over the root directory of the project and getting same error on server start.

Comment: Under `src/main` create `webapp` directory. And under `webapp`, create `WEB-INF`. Simply put your persistance.xml file in `WEB-INF' there. Do not create `classes` directory. The `classes` directory is created in the `target` directory when maven builds your project.

Comment: tried putting `persistence.xml` file under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF` directory, but getting same error on server startup, because now it shows the error on the root folder and `Java Resources` folder of the project, with a small red colored cross icon. Seems it's not able to find the `persistence.xml` under `/src/main/java/META-INF` folder. When I put `persistence.xml` file back under `META-INF` folder, it doesn't show error. Is there not any way to tell maven to include the file into `WEB-INF/classes` directory from `META-INF` directory during build ?

Comment: A little thing I just noticed. Use attribute `unitName=TELCOAppPu` and not `name=TELCOAppPu` in the annotation `@PersistenceContext()` on top of `EntityManager`. This should solve your issue.